# Asynchronous programming - creating file if doesn't exist and then reading it

Tags: node.js, async-await

I am writing an authentication microservice in Node.js that talks to AD FS, and I'm having a problem reading a file at the right time. I am still pretty new to Node.js, and asynchronous programming. I am trying to use a Passport module, and it requires a certificate for the AD FS server. In the past, I have just downloaded the certificate manually, and put it in a place the program can read, but I want to get away from that, and create it on demand the first time around. I can create the certificate in a toy program without problems, but when I try to incorporate it into the larger program, I run into an asynchronous/race condition problem where the file isn't available yet. I'm essentially trying to do:

```
//pseudo code
if (file does not exist) {
    create_file();
    return read_file();
}
else {
    return read_file();
}
```

The problem is in the getAdfsCertificate function. I don't know how to wait for the write to be done. I think I need to do

```
writeCertificate(x509CertificateStr, adfsCertificateFilename)
    .then(() => return fs.readFileSync(adfsServerCertFilename));
```

but I am unsure of the syntax, and I think I am mixing and matching promises with async/await.

Snippets of my code follows:

This is where the certificate is requested

```
passport.use(new Strategy(
    {
        jwt: {
            algorithm: 'RS256'
        },
        cert: getAdfsCertificate(process.env.ADFS_SERVER, adfsServerCertFilename),
        path: '',
        realm: process.env.REALM,
        homeRealm: '',
        identityProviderUrl: process.env.IDENTITY_PROVIDER_URL,
        thumbprint: process.env.ADFS_THUMBPRINT
    },
    function (profile, done) {
        // console.log("Auth with", profile);
        if (!profile.upn) {
            return done(new Error("No upn found"), null);
        }
        done(null, profile);
    }
));
```

these are the relevant functions for getting the certificate, and creating if necessary:

```
async function getAdfsCertificate(adfsServer, adfsCertificateFilename) {
    let fileExists = await fs.promises.access(adfsCertificateFilename).then(() => true).catch(() => false);

    if (!fileExists) {
        console.log('certificate file does not exist');
        
        console.log('fetching FederationMetadata from AD FS Server');
        var xmlResponse = await getFederationMetadataXml(adfsServer);
        
        console.log('extracting x509 certificate from xml');
        var x509CertificateStr = await parseX509FromFederationMetaData(xmlResponse);
        
        console.log('saving x509 certificate to file');
        await writeCertificate(x509CertificateStr, adfsCertificateFilename);
    }
    
    console.log('retrieving certificate from file');
    return fs.readFileSync(adfsServerCertFilename);
}

async function getFederationMetadataXml(adfsServer) {
    try {
        const httpsAgent = new https.Agent({ rejectUnauthorized: false });
        let response = await axios.get('https://' + adfsServer + '/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml', { httpsAgent });
        return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error getting AD FS FederationMetadData ', error);
    }
}


async function parseX509FromFederationMetaData(metadataXml) {
    try {
        var xmlDoc = libxml.parseXmlString(metadataXml);
        var x509cert = xmlDoc.get('/a:EntityDescriptor/b:Signature/b:KeyInfo/b:X509Data/b:X509Certificate',
            {
                a: 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata',
                b: 'http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#'
            });

        return x509cert.text();
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error parsing x509 from FederationMetadata', error);
    }
}

async function writeCertificate(str, filename) {
    try {
        // wrap long lines of certificate to 64 character lines
        const line_length = 64;
        const line_count = Math.ceil(str.length / line_length)

        let writestream = fs.createWriteStream(filename);

        let offset = 0;

        writestream.write('-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n');

        for (let i = 0; i < line_count; ++i) {
            writestream.write(str.substr(offset, line_length));
            writestream.write('\n');
            offset += line_length;
        }
        
        writestream.write('-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n');

        writestream.end();
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error while writing certificate file', error);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, the `let fileExists = await fs.promises...` seems too much of a promise. Are you sure: (1) you need the `fsPromises.access` (e.g. `fs.accessSync` is not suitable)? (2) Have you tried to use async/await here as well with a try...catch?

Comment: If you want to know when `writeCertificate()` is done, then it needs to return a promise that resolves when your writing is done.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the protocol of answering your own question, especially when it incorporates feedback from comments. I wanted to post an "Answer" though, so I could illustrate with fully formatted code.

I got rid of the asynchronous call to fs.promises.access, and replaced it with a fs.existsSync function. I also put in an else block to prevent the fs.readSync from being called there. Finally I used the the ".then" from the writeCertificate promise to do a fs.readSync.

```
async function getAdfsCertificate(adfsServer, adfsCertificateFilename) {
    if (! fs.existsSync(adfsCertificateFilename)) {
        // first time app is run, certificate does not exist
        // download and format appropriately
        console.log('certificate file does not exist');
        
        console.log('fetching FederationMetadata from AD FS Server');
        var xmlResponse = await getFederationMetadataXml(adfsServer);
        
        console.log('Extracting x509 certificate from xml');
        var x509CertificateStr = await parseX509FromFederationMetaData(xmlResponse);
        
        console.log('saving x509 certificate to file');
        writeCertificate(x509CertificateStr, adfsCertificateFilename)
            .then(() => { return fs.readFileSync(adfsServerCertFilename);});
    } else {
        // certificate exists, read it
        console.log('retrieving certificate from file');
        return fs.readFileSync(adfsServerCertFilename);
    }
}
```

Modified writeCertificate to return a promise. I thought declaring it as "async" was sufficient.

```
function writeCertificate(str, filename) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        // wrap long lines of certificate to 64 character lines
        const line_length = 64;
        const line_count = Math.ceil(str.length / line_length)

        let f = fs.createWriteStream(filename);

        let offset = 0;

        f.write('-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n');

        for (let i = 0; i < line_count; ++i) {
            f.write(str.substr(offset, line_length));
            f.write('\n');
            offset += line_length;
        }
        
        f.write('-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n');
        f.end();

        f.on('finish', resolve);
        f.on('error', reject);
    });
}
```

Comment: I do wonder if writeCertificate should create a buffer of the stuff it intends to write, write it all at once, instead of using a writestream, and then return the formatted buffer to eliminate the fs.readFileSync in the the ".then"